# How does the Stanford NER CRF classifier tool compute TP, FP, FN?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm observing all kinds of discrepancies in the TP, FP, FN output of a classifier I trained. For instance, the model tells me that there are no entities of type "C" detected, when in fact, I look at the output file and there are many entities properly tagged as "C".

Is there something I can read to understand how the NER tool computes its TP, FP, and FN counts?

Comment: Could you provide some details on how you are running the NER system?

Answer (score 0):

IOBUtils.java has countEntityResult that takes boundary errors into account.